# Possible to grab desc limit 1 from a previous query and assign to variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I get the last result of the last position of a previous query without having to do an entire query again? That is, I already have a query that ends like this:

```
 WHERE (stories.SID = :SID) AND (writing.approved = :approved) ORDER BY position ASC";
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What I want to do is reference that query and add desc limit 1 and then assign that result to a variable. Is there a way to something like

```
$last = $row->desc limit 1 ?
```

I know this is not remotely correct, but just giving an idea of what I want to assign to $last. If I have to redo the whole query then I will but just curious....

Comment: use a for loop to find the max item and put it in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a builtin function `end()` that returns the last element of an array. Since `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` returns an array of rows, you can just get the last entry from this array.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$last_row = end($rows);
```

See the PHP doc for the [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

a way to do this:

//get number of elements in array

```
$elements = count( $rows);
```

//get last element of zero based array

```
$last = $rows[$elements-1];
```